# MySQL Request from two tables advanced

Tags: php, mysql, database, request

I have request from my MySQL table. It looks like below:

```
SELECT s . * , if( v.ip IS NULL , 0, 1 ) AS voted, v.vote
FROM `emvc4_records` s
LEFT JOIN `emvc4_records_votes` v ON ( s.id = v.record_id
AND v.day = CURRENT_DATE
AND v.ip = '2130706433' )
WHERE 1 =1
AND `category` =2
AND `caption` LIKE '%My%'
OR `description` LIKE '%My%'
ORDER BY `rating` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

I get this result:

```
id  category    category_name   caption                 description         created                 postby  votes_up    votes_down  rating  status  have_voted  vote
5   1                           My second idea          My second idea      2013-06-04 00:00:00     102     2           0           2       0       0           NULL
7   2                           My first question       My first question   2013-06-04 00:00:00     102     2           0           2       0       0           NULL
9   2                           My second               My second question  2013-06-04 00:00:00     102     1           0           1       0       0           NULL
```

My question: In my sql query I have: "AND `category` =2". So why I get record id=5 (it has category= 1) in my output?

Thanks!

Comment: try putting parentheses around the "OR" combination. `...AND (`caption` LIKE '%My%'
OR `description` LIKE '%My%') ORDER BY...`

Comment: ? I would like to search text in caption and description also...

Comment: YES! Thanks. Should be: (caption` LIKE '%My%' OR description LIKE '%My%')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions in the `WHERE` clause are not properly organized. Add parentheses to group the conditions that you want. I guess `LIKE '%My%'` should be grouped.

```
SELECT s . *
    , if( v.ip IS NULL , 0, 1 ) AS voted
    , v.vote
    FROM `emvc4_records` s
    LEFT JOIN `emvc4_records_votes` v ON ( s.id = v.record_id
        AND v.day = CURRENT_DATE
        AND v.ip = '2130706433' )
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND `category` = 2
        AND (`caption` LIKE '%My%' OR `description` LIKE '%My%')
    ORDER BY `rating` DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 25
```

I don't why you added `1 = 1`, but you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be look like:

```
...............
`category` =2
AND (`caption` LIKE '%My%' OR `description` LIKE '%My%')
.................
```